# Find a vector field to calculate the volume of any subset using the flow through its edge.

Tags: vector-analysis

Find a vector field $v$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with wich you can calculate the volume of every open subset with a smooth edge $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ using the flow of the vector field through the edge $\partial \Omega$.

Can someone help me with this. I have a feeling that this should be kind of easy, but I cant get it...

Comment: Do you know the divergence theorem/stokes theorem in $n$ dimensions?

Comment: We only did it for 3 dimensions..

Comment: Is this a question from the class, or something from self study (trying to determine what you can use).

Comment: Its from the class. But we are pretty much left on our own with the problems. So its not unusual to have to use something we didnt do in class in order to solve the problems.

Comment: Well I suggest solving it in three dimensions with the Divergence theorem and then thinking about how that solution works in $n$ dimensions with "Stokes theorem$ applied to manifolds with boundaries.  Maybe there is some way I am not thinking of that doesn't require that machinery.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I cant figure it out. Could you help me out with this step? Which vector field can be used in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any field with divergence identically equal to $1$ will work. The are infinitely many such fields of the form 
$$
ax\vec \imath+by\vec\jmath + cz\vec k
$$
where $a+b+c=1$. Some are a little nicer than others.